# How do I hide a div behind a video element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've placed a video above a div background, The video has black background and for the video background to not be visible, I've used mix-blend-mode: screen.

Everything is working fine till now. The problem is when another elements gets behind the video (onclick animation), but still that element is visible, since the video's blend mode is screen.

Is there any way to hide the second div, when it is behind the video ?

```
 video {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 50px;
mix-blend-mode: screen;
  pointer-events:none;
}`
```

This is the background (don't know if it is releveant or not)

```
    .background{
background-color: #7a7f83;
}
```

The color of the second div is bright (yellow, blue,etc)

Edit: here's the shorter version. 
Consider 2 divs and a video. 
one div is background and one is a rectangle. 
I want to place video above both the divs, and I've kept the video blend mode to screen. 
Now as you may know, since the video blend mode is screen, everything behind the video is visible. 
I want the background div to be visible but not the rectangle div. 
Is there a way to hide the part of the rectangle div which is behind the video ?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a reduced example of the problem?

Comment: Added a easier version of the question as edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example #1**

Set Square class position to the absolute and parent (background) position to the relative.

```
.square{background-color: red;width: 100px;height: 100px;position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;}
.background{position: relative;}
```

and your video is inside background class element. like this:

```
<div class="background">
    <video>...</video>
    <div class="square">SQUARE CLASS</div>
</div>
```

if you are using z-index for video tag, your square z-index must be higher than that.

Result:

[image]

and after that If you want hide the square, just change it to the display:none; and when you need it to show change it to display: block;

**Example #2**

Do whatever you did in example #1 but you need to change your HTML like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="square">SQUARE CLASS</div>
    <div class="background">
        <video>...</video>
    </div>
</div>
```

and main class position must be relative. just like background class.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Z-index won't help me here. I want the video on top and I have the video on top, with the highest z-index. The problem is since the blend mode is set to screen (which is required for some reasons), everything behind the video is visible and hence the div behind the video is visible. I want some way for the div behind the video to be not effected by the blend mode of the video and hence be invisible when behind the video.

Comment: this is quite a good answer, but as I said, it's not that easy, since in the example you showed the entire square is behind the video, but in my case, only a part of the square is behind the video and I only want that part to be removed, not the entire square itself.

Comment: OK, Edited my answer. See Example #2. Remember, in example #2 you don't need set z-index for video tag. It works without z-index perfectly.